# This is my function for determining if a number is prime. I believe it is correct, but it keeps failing a unit test

Tags: java, primes

This is my block of code for determining if a number is prime or not which is really a simple problem. however, it does not pass the unit test and I have no idea why. I have tried different primitive variable types, but to no avail. It passes all the explicit test cases, so I have no idea which value of n it is not checking correctly of its prime status.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    boolean f = true;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt; i++) {
        if (((n % i) == 0)) {
            f = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

The unit test in question gives the result:

java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected :783904569
Actual   :3149358104

And here is the unit test code

```
    CRC32 check = new CRC32();
    for(int k = 0; k < 10_000_000; k++) {
        if(Primes.isPrime(k)) { check.update(k); }
    }
    assertEquals(783904569L, check.getValue());
}
```

I have tried everything reasonable including re writing the code differently, but it keeps giving the same answer.

Comment: How does it do with `isPrime(2)`?

Comment: @matt that number is the CRC of all the primes detected.

Comment: @Persixty it returned false, but now that I fixed it the unit test still fails.

Comment: `for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt; i++)` should use `i+=2`, not `i++`.  As to your incorrect answer, please go back and carefully re-read the Javadoc for `CRC#update(int)`

Answer (score 1):

Your `isPime()` has two mistakes:

- isPrime(1) == true
- isPrime(2) == false

The test passes if you add the following to the beginning of the method:

```
if (n == 1) return false;
if (n == 2) return true;
```

You can speed it up with [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

```
static final int MAX_PRIMES = 10_000_000 + 1;
static final boolean[] PRIMES = new boolean[MAX_PRIMES];
static {
    Arrays.fill(PRIMES, true);
    PRIMES[0] = PRIMES[1] = false;
    for (int i = 2, end = (int)Math.sqrt(MAX_PRIMES); i <= end; ++i)
        for (int j = i + i; j < MAX_PRIMES; j += i)
            PRIMES[j] = false;
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    return PRIMES[n];
}
```

Comment: Wow, the n(1) = true was the problem. Thanks for this solution! I Was pulling my hair out trying to figure this out, this shouldn't have been this hard for me. Thanks!!!